# How to use inner join in select with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I want to fetch record from mysql database on following condition

I have the following tables:

- organization_ Table

  ```
  organizationId | organizationname
  ```
- campaign Table

  ```
  camp_id | camp_name | adv_id | organizationId
  ```
- advertise Table

  ```
  adv_id | adv_name
  ```
- ad_display Table

  ```
  ad_displayId | adv_id | camp_id |
  ```

Now from ad_display table I want to fetch record like this:

```
| adv_name | camp_name | organizationname
```

With `WHERE` Condtion as Where organizationId == ?

So basically I want the advertise list of campaign where organization_id=?

> Note: there should be multiple entry for same adv_id in camapign table and same camp_id with multiple entry in ad_display

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ad.ad_displayId, a.adv_name, c.camp_name, o.organizationname 
FROM ad_display ad 
INNER JOIN advertise a ON ad.adv_id = a.adv_id 
INNER JOIN campaign c ON ad.camp_id = c.camp_id 
INNER JOIN organization o ON c.organizationId = o.organizationId 
WHERE o.organizationId = ?;
```

Comment: thnx ...its worked..actually am new to this mysql and also for sql query...but u all guys are quick..tnx for this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT Distinct
  advertise.adv_name,
  campaign.camp_name,
  organization_.organizationname
FROM
  advertise inner join campaign
  on advertise.adv_id = campaign.adv_id
  inner join organization_
  on campaign.organizationID = organization_.organizationID
WHERE
  organization_.organizationID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM campaign
LEFT JOIN ad_display ON campaign.camp_id = ad_display.camp_id
LEFT JOIN advertise ON ad_display.adv_id = advertise.adv_id
WHERE campaign.organizationId = <?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
SELECT dv_name,
       camp_name,
       organizationname
FROM   organization
       inner join campaign
               ON organization.organizationid == campaign.organizationid
       left join advertise
              ON campaign.adv_id == advertise.adv_id
WHERE  condition =? ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  advertise.adv_name, 
        campaign.camp_name, 
        organization_Table.organizationname
FROM   ad_display 
    INNER JOIN advertise ON ad_display.adv_id = advertise.adv_id 
    INNER JOIN campaign ON ad_display.camp_id = campaign.camp_id 
    INNER JOIN organization_ Table ON campaign.organizationId = organization_Table.organizationId
    AND organization_Table.organizationId=?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT batch_number,
       Count(receipt_number) AS tot_rec,
       Sum(amount)           AS tot_amount
FROM   receipt_header
GROUP  BY batch_number
UNION ALL
SELECT batch_number,
       Count(receipt_lines.receipt_number),
       Sum(receipt_lines.amount)
FROM   receipt_lines
       INNER JOIN receipt_header
               ON receipt_header.record_id = receipt_lines.header_record_id
GROUP  BY batch_number
ORDER  BY batch_number ASC;
```